# nodejs firebird connection encoding

Tags: node.js, character-encoding, database-connection, firebird2.5

I'm building app, which uses firebird database (database is a part of 3rd company software, so I can't modify it).

I used node-firebird. On test database when is set encoding/charset to UTF-8 all works, but with databases with WIN1250 I got
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPhgx.png)

Production database has WIN1250. How to connect to it?

```
 const Firebird = require('node-firebird');

 let dbConfig = {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3050,
    database: 'path',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    lowercase_keys: false,
    role: null,
    pageSize: 4096
 };

Firebird.attach(dbConfig, function (err, db) {

        if (err)
            throw err;


        db.query( SQLQUERY, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }


            db.detach();
            //some dataprocessing ...
        });
    });
```

In documentation:

> Charset for database connection is always UTF-8
>
> node-firebird doesn't let you chose the charset connection, it will always use UTF8. Node is unicode, no matter if your database is using another charset to store string or blob, Firebird will transliterate automatically.

https://github.com/hgourvest/node-firebird

Any idea, or maybe you know another package?

Comment: Please put the error message as text in your question, don't use screenshots.

Comment: Also, are you connecting to a Firebird 2.5, or Firebird 3 database (or an earlier version?)?

Answer (score 0):

That wasn't a problem with node-firebird.
Problem was with database - solution: dump database and restore :D

Answer (score 0):

I changed the variable DEFAULT_ENCONDING inside the index.js file of the lib node-firebird to latin1 and it seems to work.